# C# WebRequest (Http POST over SSL) hangs at GetResponse() but different URL works. Also wrong POST parameters in a request

Tags: c#, post, ssl, timeout, httprequest

I found that this code works as expected:

```
var url = "https://limal.info/efulfilment.php";
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
var alternativeAnswer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new WebClient().UploadValues(url, new NameValueCollection() { { "xml", "test" } }));
```

The following code however gives me a headache:

```
var url = "https://limal.info/efulfilment.php";
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "POST";
request.Timeout = 5000; // I added this for you, so you only need to wait 5 sec...

using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream);
    writer.Write("xml=test");
}
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        var answer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Somehow the post parameters don't get recognized and I get the response:

```
"limal.info bridge error: Missing 'xml' variable in post request."
```

(The correct answer would be that the XML data is wrongly formatted, as *test* is invalid XML...)

**Now to the next Problem:**

When I use a different url a timeout exception occurs. It hangs at *UploadValues* in the following code. (The other example that uses *HttpWebRequest* hangs at *GetResponse*, which I tried, too.)

```
var url = "https://sys.efulfilment.de/rt/";
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
var alternativeAnswer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new WebClient().UploadValues(url, new NameValueCollection() { { "xml", "test" } }));
```

I read about similar problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063937/httpwebrequest-getresponse-hangs-the-second-time-it-is-called) and on other sites. It seems that using Http POST with SSL is a problem in .NET.

WHY?? :(

Comment: Problem 1 solved: I echoed the HTTP request and saw that it was empty. It appears, that the StreamWriter only actually writes when you flush it.

    writer.Write("xml=test");
    writer.Flush();

Comment: Re Problem 1. The StreamWriter should be created in a using block too, that will cause the flush. It will also close the Stream too; but maybe just leave the Stream using block in the code for readability.

Comment: Problem 2 gets solved here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2012/03/29/https-request-hangs-.net-application-connection-on-tls-server-name-indicator-warning.aspx